# How come using variables in preg_match_all fails in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to include variables in my pattern for preg_match_all. I've tried several ways and none of them seem to work - even when the pattern is correct upon echo.

Here's what I have:

First Attempt (using single quotes to be safe):

```
    $pattern_areacode = '/\<a name\=\"'. $code . '\"\>'. $code . '\<\/a\>.*?(\<td\b[^>]*\>       (.*?)\<\/td\>).*?<\/tr\>/';
    preg_match_all($pattern_areacode, $contents, $ac_match);
```

issue: I printed the pattern and it looked fine. Yet it's not returning any results.

Second Attempt (Using double):

```
    $pattern_areacode = "/\<a name\=\"$code\"\>$code\<\/a\>.*?(\<td\b[^>]*\>(.*?)\<\/td\>).*?<\/tr\>/";
    preg_match_all($pattern_areacode, $contents, $ac_match);
```

issue: The double quotes before $ get escaped. Weird.

I did my research and tried a bunch of other ways as well, including using braces {}, but to no avail.

How do I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Also see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: "and it looked fine" .. well it obviously wasn't fine. otherwise it would work.

Comment: Looks like you're a little overly paranoid with your escaping there.  I don't think you need to escape `<` or `=`.  If you could give us sample values for `$code` and `$contents` it'd be easier for us to help.

Comment: `even when the pattern is correct upon echo.` -- give an example for correct pattern and text it should match

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your inputs are escaped and don't contain anything that regex may interpret as a pattern (which could make your match fail). This can be done easily using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php). So, if you haven't already:

```
$code = preg_quote($quote);
```

Also, I recommend using an actual HTML parser as opposed to regex matches, maybe look in to using the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: the argument is a 3 digit integer so I don't think escaping will be neccessary